# how to do filtering from array in angular

Tags: html, css, arrays, angular, filtering

I have this data in my tags.ts file and I'm not sure how I can do filtering using the name. I was able to do it using a normal string list but not sure how to do it for arrays. any suggestion or help, how to do that.

```
export const tags2: Array<Tag> = [{name: "Lam", superTag: true},
{name: "Eliz", superTag: false},
{name: "Cathy", superTag: true},
{name: "John", superTag: false},
{name: "James", superTag: false},
{name: "David", superTag: false}];
```

Below code is working fine for a normal string list but not for arrays

```
import { tags2 } from "./tags.data";

    this._filteredTags = this.tags.filter((v: string) =>
      v.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.toLowerCase().trim())
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You you have to check the name instead on `toLowerCase()` on object

```
this._filteredTags = this.tags.filter((v: string) =>
    v["name"].toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.toLowerCase().trim())
);
```